# Merge two MySQL query and get distance between two zip codes

Tags: php, mysql, geocoding, latitude-longitude, google-latitude

i want to get distance between two zip codes.

`HTML` form have a field i.e ZIP CODE, Miles(distance).\

DB structure with 7000 records.

```
id | name | zip_code | lat | lng | status|
```

MySQL query

```
   $query =  "SELECT *, 3963 * acos(cos(radians(90-lat ))*cos(radians(90-'".$result['lat']."'))".
              "+sin(radians(90-lat ))* sin(radians(90-'".$result['lat']."'))".
              "*cos(radians(lng- '".$result['lng']."'))) AS distance FROM table_name".
              " WHERE memberLevel='basic' HAVING (distance < '".$miles."') 
                ORDER BY distance ASC";
```

I don't know what is the right MySQL query to compare distance with input and stored latitude,longitude.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about the result set you require? What controls the number of rows? What should each row contain? Exactly what parameters will you present to the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the spacial functions and spacial type columns http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/spatial-extensions.html

Here it's a great example to use spacial functions!
http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/10/21/using-the-new-spatial-functions-in-mysql-5-6-for-geo-enabled-applications/

Or you can define a custom function

`` CREATE DEFINER=`test`@`%` FUNCTION `geoDistance`(`lon1` DOUBLE, `lat1` DOUBLE, `lon2` DOUBLE, `lat2` DOUBLE)
    RETURNS double
    LANGUAGE SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
    NO SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
    BEGIN
    DECLARE v DOUBLE;
    SELECT cos(radians(lat1))
        * cos(radians(lat2))
        * cos(radians(lon2) - radians(lon1)) 
        + sin(radians(lat1)) 
        * sin(radians(lat2)) INTO v;
    RETURN IF(v > 1, 0, 6371000 * acos(v));
END ``

then call

`SELECT geoDistance(X(point1), Y(point1), X(spoint2), Y(point2))
result comes in meters`